# C# Generic Constraints not working correctly

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I have the following code:

```
public interface IEnrollment
{
    bool IsGood { get; set; }
}

public interface IEnrollmentToRegion
{
    int RegionId { get; set; }
}

public class ByRegion : IEnrollmentToRegion
{
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
}

public class Enrollment : IEnrollment
{
    public bool IsGood { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ByRegion> Regions { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var e = new Enrollment();
        if (isEnrolled(e, c => c.Any(l => l.RegionId == 10)))
        {

        }
    }

    private bool isEnrolled<T>(Enrollment enrollment, Func<ICollection<T>, bool> test) where T : IEnrollmentToRegion
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create the method isEnrolled that takes and object of the type IEnrollment and in this method I will do a bunch of checks to see if it return true or not.  One of the things that I want to check is a collection of objects (in the above example it is simplified to only have 1 single class the ByRegion class, but in my real there are multiple Enrollment classes each with it's own separate collections under them that are of different types, but all of the types have a property called RegionId.

So I want to pass in a function that will check these various collections to see if the RegionId is in the collection.  The problem that I'm having is that I get an error on the line
`c.Any(l => l.RegionId == 10))` saying that it doesn't know what RegionId is.  In fact when I hit the . after the `l` I do not get any intellisense drop down.  I'm not sure why I don't get any dropdown because there is a restriction on T that T should be of the IEnrollmentToRegion type and that type has RegionId on it.

Comment: That works great thanks.  Always the simplest things

Comment: So, whats the problem, does this work now? If so, delete the question, or post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that while a `ByRegion` is an `IEnrollmentToRegion`, an `ICollection<ByRegion>` is not a `ICollection<IEnrollmentToRegion>`. You can test this using reflection:

```
//Returns true
return typeof(IEnrollmentToRegion).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ByRegion));

//Returns false
return typeof(ICollection<IEnrollmentToRegion>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ICollection<ByRegion>));
```

So you can't just specify `T` and let type inference take care of it for you. In fact, even if you specified the type explicitly, like:

```
isEnrolled<IEnrollmentToRegion>(e, c => c.Any(l => l.RegionId == 10))
```

You'd find that once you try to write the actual contents of `isEnrolled<T>`, you'd run into problems.

Here's an updated version of your code that works:

```
public interface IEnrollment<T> where T:IEnrollmentToRegion
    {
        bool IsGood { get; set; }
        ICollection<T> Regions { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IEnrollmentToRegion
    {
        int RegionId { get; set; }
    }

    public class ByRegion : IEnrollmentToRegion
    {
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Enrollment : IEnrollment<ByRegion>
    {
        public bool IsGood { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ByRegion> Regions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var e = new Enrollment();
            e.Regions = new List<ByRegion>() { new ByRegion { RegionId = 10 } };

            if (isEnrolled(e, c => c.Any(l => l.RegionId == 10)))
            {
                //This line gets hit
            }
        }

        private bool isEnrolled<T>(IEnrollment<T> enrollment, Func<ICollection<T>, bool> test) where T : IEnrollmentToRegion
        {
            return test(enrollment.Regions);
        }
```